# A controller with this name is not

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I work project angular js in frontend and symfony in backend but I have this bug:

https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$controller/ctrlreg?p0=httpgetctrl

this is code index.html.twig:

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}
    {% block title %} Acceuil {% endblock %}
    {% block stylesheets %}<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootswatch/3.3.7/cerulean/bootstrap.min.css">
    <style>

    a {
        text-decoration:none;
        color: #e74c3c;
            margin-right: 25px;

    }

    </style>

    {% endblock %}
    {% block body %}
    <div class="container" ng-app="myApp">
        <a href="#/!">Acceuil</a>

    <a href="#!login">Login</a>
    <a href="#!register">Register</a> <br><br>

    <div ng-view></div>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.5/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.5/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/todc-bootstrap/3.3.7-3.3.13/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('bundles/fosjsrouting/js/router.js') }}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ path('fos_js_routing_js', {"callback": "fos.Router.setData"}) }}"></script>
    <scritp src="app.js"></script>
    <script>
    var app = angular.module("myApp", ["ngRoute"]);
    var m =angular

    app.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
      $routeProvider
        .when("/login", {
          templateUrl: Routing.generate('login',
            {template:"default/login.html.twig"})
        })
        .when("/register", {
          templateUrl: Routing.generate('register',
            {template:"default/registere.html.twig"}),
          controller: 'httpgetctrl',  
        });
    }]);

    </script>

    </div>
    {% endblock %}
```

this is code app.js:

```
    var app = angular.module("reg", []);
    app.controller("httpgetctrl", function ($scope, $http) {

        $scope.SendData = function () {
           // use $.param jQuery function to serialize data from JSON 
            var data = $.param({
                username: $scope.username,
                email: $scope.email,
                pass: $scope.password,
                confir: $scope.confirmationpass
            });

            var config = {
                headers : {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8;'
                }
            }

            $http.post("{{path('register')}}", data, config)
            .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                console.log("success");
            })
            .error(function (data, status, header, config) {
                console.log("error");
            });
        };

    });
```

and this is code registere.html.twig:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Register</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootswatch/3.3.7/cerulean/bootstrap.min.css">
<style>

body{
    background-color: #525252;
}
.centered-form{
    margin-top: 60px;
}

.centered-form .panel{
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
    box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3) 20px 20px 20px;
}

a {
    text-decoration:none;
    color: #e74c3c;
        margin-right: 25px;

}

</style>
</head>
<body ng-app="reg">
<div class="container" >
        <div class="row centered-form">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8 col-md-4 col-sm-offset-2 col-md-offset-4">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                        <h3 class="panel-title text-center" >Register</h3>
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel-body">
                        <form role="form">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div >
                                    <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="text" name="first_name" id="first_name" ng-model="username" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="Username">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6">

                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="email" name="email" id="email" ng-model="email" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="Email Address">
                            </div>

                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <input type="password" name="password" ng-model="password" id="password" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="Password">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <input type="password" name="password_confirmation" ng-model="confirmationpass" id="password_confirmation" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="Confirm Password">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <input type="submit" value="Register" ng-click="SendData()" class="btn btn-info btn-block">

                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.5/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/todc-bootstrap/3.3.7-3.3.13/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>



</body>
</html>
```

help me please for resolve this bug

Answer (score 0):

In `httpgetctrl` controller change

```
 var app = angular.module("reg", []);
```

to

```
    var app = angular.module("myApp", ["ngRoute"]);
```

Comment: also bug my friend :(

Comment: remove `ng-app="reg"` from `registere.html` file

Comment: you should inject `app.js` after `var app = angular.module("myApp", ["ngRoute"]); ....` tag script in `index.html`

Comment: please put router config in separate file and inject it before controllers.